# Return true for all parts of media query before excuting

Tags: css

How do I modify the following media query so that the entire query has to be true before being executed?

`@media only handheld and (max-device-width : 414px) and (orientation : portrait) {
}`

**Goal**: Query is only executed if the browser resides on a smartphone or tablet, in portrait, with a screen width of less than 414px.

Thank you.

Comment: Not possible without the use of javascript, css cannot detect what device you are using.

Comment: You're not going to get a browser that small on a desktop unless people resize it down to that size which, if they do, does it matter if they see your mobile layout?